# SPARQL Query with quantifier

Tags: sparql

I need to query using quantifier such as ANY(∀).
For example:

Data

```
:a :to :b . (b is a non_target_type)
:b :to :c . (c is a target_type)
:c :to :d . (d is a non_target_type)
:d :to :e . (e is a target_type)
:e :to :f . (f is a target_type)
```

A query is like

```
:a -> ?y -> ?z .
?z a :target_type .
∀?y, ?y is not a :target_type . (Here's the problem)
```

Then I expect to get ?z only contains :c
How can I get the result by sparql?

Comment: Have you tried something like:
`SELECT * WHERE {:a :to* ?first_tgt_type . ?first_tgt_type a :target_type FILTER NOT EXISTS {?first_tgt_type a :target_type  }}`

Comment: Yes, I've tried this kind. But "NOT EXISTS" is an existential quantifier, so when ?y is :d, and ?z is :f, it also satisfies the pattern (example: select ?z where {:a :to+ ?y. ?y :to+ ?z. ?z a :target_type. FILTER NOT EXISTS {?y a :target_type}}, it return ?z is the list which contains :c, :e, :f).

Comment: that's not correct what you're saying. Your constraint `∀?y, ?y is not a :target_type` which is more formally `∀?y: ¬∃ (?y a :target_type)` can be reformulated by common laws to `¬∃?y:(?y a :target_type)`, so the suggested query is correct. `NOT EXISTS` denotes the absence of the given information. You'll need `:to*` plus an appending triple pattern

Comment: Please see my answer below. I have a more specific problem description.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're asking for

```sql
SELECT ?z WHERE {
  :a :to ?y .
  ?y :to ?z .
  ?z a :targetType .
  FILTER NOT EXISTS {
    ?y a :targetType
  }
}
```

This finds *any* ?z such that:

- `?z a :target_type`; and
- `:a` is connected to something that is connected to ?z; and
- it's not the case that `?y a :targetType`

That would be mean that :a is connected through *some* ?y to `:z` such that ?y isn't a :targetType.  But if you want to make sure that there's *no* such ?y that is a :targetType, you'd use:

```sql
SELECT ?z WHERE {
  :a :to/:to ?z .
  ?z a :targetType .
  FILTER NOT EXISTS {
    :a :to ?y .
    ?y :to ?z .
    ?y a :targetType
  }
}
```

Comment: Please see my answer below. I have a more specific problem description.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the graph and query result. What I expect is result ":d", other than ":d and :g".

```
@prefix ns: <http://example/> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

ns:a ns:to ns:b .
ns:b ns:to ns:c .
ns:c ns:to ns:d .
ns:d ns:to ns:e .
ns:e ns:to ns:f .
ns:f ns:to ns:g .
ns:g ns:to ns:h .

ns:a rdf:type ns:target .
ns:d rdf:type ns:target .
ns:g rdf:type ns:target .
```

[image]